# Adding key to ssh agent when shell is opened

Tags: shell, ssh

Why isn't this code working in my `.bash_profile`?

```
echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK
if [ -z "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ]; then
        ssh-add
fi
```

My identity is not getting added when shell is opened. The variable `$SSH_AUTH_SOCK` is being echoed when the shell opens:

```
/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.UKHCb6uhHB/Listeners
```

So if the variable is defined, why isn't the `ssh-add` statement being evaluated?

If I run `ssh-add` manually from the command line, or place it on it's own separate line of my `.bash_profile`, it successfully runs and adds my identity to the ssh agent.

Additionally, making thing simpler and just trying to echo a value doesn't work, for example, I do not see `test` being echoed after placing this in the file:

```
echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK
if [ -z "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ]; then
    echo test
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Whoops, I was using the wrong operator. Should be `-n`, not `-z`.